# How to run a single test package and its subpackages in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, maven, junit

I have a Java/Maven project, my test are under src/test/java. There I have two packages integration and unit each with subpackages. I would like to run all test inside the unit package and it's subpackages.

I am using JUnit4 and Eclipse Kepler SR2.

I know that with right click -> run as it should run but somehow Eclipse doesn't find any tests.

This works:

- running each test alone
- running all tests by right clicking on src/test/java -> run as.
- running only unit tests with mvn test (using the surefire plugin)

But I want to use some codecoverage plugin for eclipse and for that I need to run the tests in eclipse without the integration tests. And it is not a problem of the coverage tool, vanillia run as junit test also doesn't work.

The test classes get compiled to target/test-classes. And they are there :-/

So any suggestions what causes this?

**EDIT:**

Okay it seems like eclipse only executes tests directly in the selected package. How to also execute tests in subpackages?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the eclipse specifics, but you could try a test suite, and set up to run that. It might be easier to point to than a package.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({
    unit.OneClass.class, 
    unit.TwoClass.class
})
public class UnitTestSuite {
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do (run all tests in a package by right clicking on it) should work in principle. Certainly does for me in Eclipse Kepler SR2.

If it's not working, presumably the reason is one of:

- old version of Eclipse
- corrupted install
- corrupted project
- wrong classpath settings
- some inconsistency between junit3/4
- clicking on the wrong thing

Comment: I am using Eclipse Kepler SR2. The project itself runs, builds perfectly with maven. Clicking on the wrong thing it is definitly not XD

Comment: By 'project' and 'classpath', I mean the .project and .classpath files that eclipse uses to store Java project configuration. Maven will never read those (with m2e it will optionally write them). So  if it works in maven, that makes a problem there more likely.

Comment: .classpath and .project look fine. In an other project I can execute on package...

Answer (score 0):

You might try using cobertura. You have maven project so Using MAVEN command **mvn cobertura:cobertura** in the project level generates the code coverage under /target/site/cobertura/index.html

However there is also a plugin names as **eclemma** which might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse release 2023-03 (4.27) now does this out of the box. You can right click a package and run all tests and it will run sub package tests now too.

https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.27/jdt.php#junit-subpackage-support